# Copying Tabulator data from one table to multiple tables using the setData() function produces unpredictable results

Tags: tabulator, virtual-dom

I am using `Tabulator` for client-side entry and editing of tabular data.  In my application I have need to copy the data from a single [Crew Leader] table to one or more [Crew Member] tables.  After data for the [Crew Leader] is entered I am making use of a `button` to trigger the copying process to the [Crew Member] tables.  This is accomplished using the `Tabulator setData()` function which works as expected.

After data has been copied to the [Crew Member] tables it is necessary to edit each row with information pertinent to the individual [Crew Member].  The on-screen editing process works as expected.

My problem arises when I go to export the data.  Note, the data in my `JSON` string:

- is not the same as what appears on-screen; and
- is the same for all [Crew Member] tables.

It appears the changes being applied to one [Crew Member] table are being applied (in the virtual DOM) to all [Crew Member] tables.  Stated differently, with two "cloned" tables the changes applied to table one are applied to table two in the virtual DOM but not on-screen (and *vice versa*).

Client-side script which does the copying from the [Crew Leader] table to the [Crew Member] table(s):

```
function CloneTable() {
    var tableCrewLeader = Tabulator.prototype.findTable('#CrewLeaderTable')[0];
    var dataCrewLeader = tableCrewLeader.getData();
    if (tableCrewLeader.getDataCount() > 0) {
        // Verify a Tabulator table is present for each selected [Crew Member] by
        // looping through each <div> element with the class "crew-member-card".
        $(".crew-member-card").each(function () {
            if ($(this).attr('id').length > 0) {
                const divId = "#" + $(this).attr('id').replace('Card', 'Table');
                const tableMember = Tabulator.prototype.findTable(divId);
                if (tableMember.length > 0) {
                    const tableCrewMember = Tabulator.prototype.findTable(divId)[0];
                    tableCrewMember.setData(dataCrewLeader);
                }
                else {
                    console.log("The Tabulator table " + divId+ " was not found.");
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

It is also worth noting, **these anomalies do not occur when the data for the [Crew Member] tables is entered directly** (no `setData()` method is used).  On-screen edits/changes are not reflected in other tables when data was not copied to the table originally.

For what it's worth, the following is the loop I use to verify the contents of each [Crew Member] table row (using Firefox Web Console to view the log):

```
var dataCrewMember = tableCrewMember.getData();
$(dataCrewMember).each(function () {
    console.log(this);
});
```

**EDIT**

I have eliminated the disparity between the on-screen data and the exported data by setting the `reactiveData` attribute in my `Tabulator` constructor, as follows:

```
var table = new Tabulator(divid, {
    height: "100%",
    layout: "fitDataFill",
    reactiveData: true, //enable reactive data
    movableRows: true, 
    tabEndNewRow: true, 
    rowContextMenu: myActionContextMenu,
    keybindings: {
        "navUp": true, 
        "navDown": true, 
                },
                columns: [
                    { title: "Phase Code", field: "Phasecode", width: 144, editor: "select", editorParams: { values: function (cell) { return window.laborPhaseCodes; } } },
                    { title: "Date Worked", field: "DateComp", hozAlign: "center", sorter: "date", editor: dateEditor },
                    { title: "Start Time", field: "TimeStart", hozAlign: "center", sorter: "time", editor: timeEditor },
                    { title: "Finish Time", field: "TimeFinish", hozAlign: "center", sorter: "time", editor: timeEditor },
                    { title: "Memo", field: "Memo", width: 144, hozAlign: "left", editor: "input" },
                    { title: cloneString, headerSort: false, headerClick: CloneTable, rowHandle: true, formatter: "handle" }
                ],
            });
```

Note, however, I am still experiencing the issue wherein a change made in one [Crew Member] table is automatically replicated within the other [Crew Member] tables.  This only happens when the data in the [Crew Member] tables has been populated using the `setData()` method.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @nrayburn-tech I am hoping you might be able to weigh in on this one.  Thanks.

Comment: I am having an issue understanding the problem.  Here is an example where I copy data from one table to another.  Then I can change the data in any of the tables, and the value is independent of the others as expected.  If this isn't what you are seeing, you may need to shorten your question so it is easier to understand. https://jsfiddle.net/nrayburn/85ecbvys/22/

Comment: You've nailed it. In reviewing your code, I've noticed a couple of differences. First, the `divs` you created for the leader and two members are created at the `window.load` event. For my purposes, the leader `div` is created at `window.load` but my 1-to-x member `divs` are created dynamically, as names are selected from a list. Second, you are passing the `div` object to the `tabulator` constructor. The examples I've seen pass the element `id` as a string. Is there a difference? I can't seem to get the `tabulator` constructor to work with a `div` object reference. Thoughts? Thanks again.

Comment: Can you post your html for the leader table and two crew members before the Tabulator is created?  And, there isn't really a difference between using the id or the div.  I pass in the div because I create it in the JavaScript.  Here is an example using divs that are in the html.  https://jsfiddle.net/nrayburn/85ecbvys/25/

Comment: I am working on a fiddle that I hope will replicate my issue.  I will let you know what I come up with.  Thanks again.

Comment: Here is a jsFiddle link that should help illustrate the problem: 
 https://jsfiddle.net/t5fh1ak6/1/

Comment: ...Uh.  I see the issue, but I am quite confused.  I will see if I can get you an answer later.  I am definitely puzzled.

Comment: Your help is greatly appreciated.  I'm glad to know it's not just me!  I am tinkering with work-arounds but I really need to be able to create `Tabulator` tables on-the-fly.  I'm loving `Tabulator` and stumbled onto this issue while testing my database upload.  I happened to look at the `JSON` string and noticed the problem. Thanks again.

Comment: Also, I apologize for the laborious original post but I think we both see it was not a simple problem.  Hopefully, there is a simple answer.

Comment: I apologize but I have another question for you.  I thought it best to simply ask rather than post a separate question on SO.  Is there a way to delete/close/remove a `Tabulator` table after it has been created?  I've browsed the documentation but haven't found anything.  Thanks.

Comment: You can definitely create them as needed without issue, but your example is causing some odd issue.  I assume that just deleting the div that the table is attached to removes the table instance.  As long as you don't have any variables still pointing to the table then all of the memory should be garbage collected.

Comment: ...So I found the issue, but I can't really say exactly why it is.  Let me cleanup my example and I will post it.

Comment: Sorry, I was typing a response to your earlier fiddle and did not see your latest comment.  I will wait for your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside of your `cloneTables` function, you set `dataCrewLeader = tableCrewLeader.getData()`.  Then you use `dataCrewLeader` as the value in each of the newly created tables.  I can only assume that these are being passed as a reference because they are objects.  So, changing one changes them all.  (I don't know if this is a bug or if it is expected that tabulator create copies when calling `setData()`.)

To fix this, instead of setting a variable to the value.  You want to call `.getData()` multiple times.  So, you could do `tableCrewMember.setData(tableCrewMember.getData())` and it will work as expected.

You can comment/uncomment the lines inside of the `copyData` function from the below example to see the issue.

Edited the example, so that it works without changing anything.
https://jsfiddle.net/nrayburn/85ecbvys/36/

Comment: Sorry but there is still an issue with the member tables. In your fiddle the on-screen data doesn't change, however, when you click the "Compare Data" button you will note the issue. To reproduce this behavior: (a) click on the "Create Tables" button; (b) click on the "Copy Leader Data" button; (c) modify the [Last Name] of the two rows of the first member table to 'Roberts' and 'Johnson', respectively; (d) click on the "Compare Data" button.  Note, even though the onscreen data is unaffected the [Last Name] values for both member tables has been changed.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain it.  In the example, it is currently 'broken'.  In the copyData function at line 68, read the comments and modify the code there to make it work as you expect.  So, comment out lines 70 - 72 and uncomment 74-75 and it will work how you expect it to.

Comment: I updated the example in the answer, so that you don't have to change anything and it works as you expect it to.

Comment: The updated example seems to work perfectly.  I see it clearly now.  Reassigning the same variable (default by reference), in essence, meant every table was sharing the same object reference. It kinda takes me back to my old days with VB.Net and passing objects ByVal and ByRef. I am going to continue testing my solution and, hopefully, becoming more familiar with `Tabulator`.  Thanks again.  Professionals like you are what make Stackoverflow work for the rest of us.